# What is the ISO document for SWD?

Tags: swd

I would like to know, is there any standard document is exist for SWD (serial wire debug protocol). As I know for JTAG they have a standard document like IEEE 1149-1, similarly is there any standard document for SWD (serial wire debug protocol),

I’ve tried on internet, I found the SWD is low pin count debug solution, but I didn’t get exactly what is the standard document number. Anybody have information about this?

Comment: According to Wikipedia: *Serial Wire Debug (SWD) is an alternative 2-pin electrical interface that **uses the same protocol [as JTAG IEEE 1149-1]**. It uses the existing GND connection. SWD uses an ARM CPU standard bi-directional wire protocol, defined in the ARM Debug Interface v5. This enables the debugger to become another AMBA bus master for access to system memory and peripheral or debug registers...*

Answer (score 1):

i think this would be the propitiatory to arm. you can find some technical document from their website which could help.

https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0031/c/IHI0031C_debug_interface_as.pdf could help